# Re-create the button touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In a `UIViewController`, I have 4 buttons. User runs the app and touch on any of the four buttons and some method gets called. I want to recreate these actions done by the user as a replay, so I need the button on which user tapped and the `UIControlEvent` on it?

Please recommend a solution.

Comment: does timing matter? or only pressing order is satisfactory?

Comment: Not clear about what you want. Could you explain more?

Comment: @erkanyildiz timing too matters. The correct lag time between two actions by user should be recorded clearly.

Comment: @sunkehappy For example, You got an app with you, it had 5 buttons in it, you pressed the 3rd one and some method got called, say a page number 3 got presented. Now as a developer I need to know on which button you pressed, what event occured and what action does took place on your touch so that I can recreate all what you have done with the app. Timing between the user actions should be noted as such.

Comment: If you just want statistics you can use one of the mobile analytics platforms with event logging (e.g. Countly http://count.ly). But if you are going to use it in your application, you need to handle it yourself.